# Was Community meant to own this bounty?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounty

There's a bounty that's owned by Community on [a question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33185/difference-between-naive-bayes-multinomial-naive-bayes) in which the original asker's account seems to be intact.

Was the bounty taken out by a second party whose account was deleted, or is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: A user quit CV today (the one who offered the bounty), in these cases they are replaced by the user [Community](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) for some esoteric-programming reason. More information [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115503/destroying-a-user-can-leave-a-bounty-open-on-a-deleted-question) and many other discussions in [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions), *e.g.* [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63873/why-was-this-bounty-awarded-by-community).

Comment: I wonder how the bounty gets awarded now. I know that half of it goes to the highest upvoted answer (with 2+) **after** the bounty was opened but I wonder if it's at all possible to get the full amount. [This meta SO thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99740/bounty-given-by-community-randomly) seems to indicate it is not possible, but it's not clear.

Comment: Thanks @Procrastinator. I was not sure this was this user who offered that bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **Procrastinator** was kind enough to mention in comments, this is standard practice when a user has deleted him/herself while the bounty was open. For further reading, consider these links:

- [Destroying a user can leave a bounty open on a deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115503/destroying-a-user-can-leave-a-bounty-open-on-a-deleted-question)
- [Why was this bounty awarded by community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63873/why-was-this-bounty-awarded-by-community)

Comment: You are everywhere! :)  Thanks for confirming.  I had read the post in question earlier that day, and I think it was from a user with a fair amount of rep, so I was surprised that he quit the same day.

Comment: @jonsca Haha yeah I'm tidying up the meta a little bit. Of course, in the course of tidying I might be mussing up the meta front page. Let me know if I'm being a bit extreme. At least this way some older stuff gets new eyes, right?

Comment: @jonsca but yes, this is `[status-bydesign]` behavior for sure! Community is the anon user's best friend.

Comment: Nah, there's 9 whole question slots on there that haven't been edited by you (yet).  Go for the gusto.

Comment: @jonsca OH NO It's been that bad, huh? Ah well, it's a one-time pain, and at least it's keeping Friday interesting, right? :D